# How to act on the currently highlighted search result with evil mode?

Tags: evil, selection

When using evil mode search, is there a way to act on the currently highlighted search result by...

- Converting it into a selection.
- Treating it as a text object.
- Having the ability to specify the end of the match when editing.

Example edits could be:

- Delete the text.
- Make the text upper case.
- Change the text for something else.

This something I often want to do when the search is only part of a word, in this case operating on the word is editing past the part of the word I searched for.

Answer (score 2):

After looking into VIM documentation, I found a way to do this which works in evil-mode too. See [Visual select current search result](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7227/301).

---

`gn` selects the highlighted text, after pressing this you can operate on the selection.

Pressing `n.` repeats the operation on the next match.

---

Note that you may use `gn` in place of `w` in many operations.

- `cgn` can be used to change the current search result.
- `gUgn` makes the search result upper case.
- `dgn` to delete the current highlight.

---

While this on it's own is useful, it would be nice to have a way to enable select-on-search (for example, if the search began in visual mode, or if `gn` was pressed on the previous search result), this is a bit out of the scope of this question though.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point in your question I do not know a default way, but you could define a custom function (and bind it to some key) yourself to change the last match to a selection so that you can further edit it the evil way:

```
(defun my-evil-last-match-to-region ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-visual-select evil-ex-search-match-beg evil-ex-search-match-end))
```

You could bind it to `t` (or `f`), which are keys with similar functionality that I guess most users do not use both:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "t") 'my-evil-last-match-to-region)
```

Subsequently, you can edit it the evil way using e.g. `d`, `U`, `c`. Or you could "specify the end/beginning of the match" using `l`/`oh`.